# c# plug in string value

Tags: c#, arrays, variables

Not sure how to do this. Simplified things for readability. Actual code does more.

Read column from file. Values are aaa, bbb, ccc.

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\mice\file.csv");
```

Declare/define string variables.

```
string aaa = "123"
string bbb = "456"
string ccc = "789"
int counter = 0;
```

I want to write a loop that reads each column value and prints out its string value.

```
While (...)
{
   Console.WriteLine(lines[counter] + " |" + lines[counter] + "|");
}
```

But the print out is:   aaa |aaa|

Whereas, I want the print out to be:   aaa |123

QUESTION: How do I adjust the 2nd part of the WriteLine to print the value of 123 instead of aaa?

Thanks.

Comment: `ReadAllLines` gives you *rows*, not columns.

Comment: @crashmstr - edited the Q. Changed columns to lines. Just symantics but yeah, using "columns" could cause some confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to dynamically get the contents of a *variable* by it's name, which is not possible in C#.  If it were a class member you could use reflection, but an even better option is a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string, string>();
map["aaa"] = "123";
map["bbb"] = "456";
map["ccc"] = "789";

while (...)
{
   Console.WriteLine(lines[counter] + " |" + map[lines[counter]] + "|");
}
```

Comment: bravo, this works, thank you!   just need a ; at the end of the first line ...   <string, string>();

Answer (score 1):

Alright I think I get what you're trying to do. You have 3 values in a csv file on a line. First you need to get the lines you've done that. Then for each line you need to split it into it's comma separated columns using

```
string[] columns = lines[counter].Split(',');
```

Now you should be able to print each column of the lines with

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1} | {2}", columns[0], columns[1], columns[2]);
```

Comment: @RAguilar - csv has 3 lines. Each line has one value. First line is "aaa". Second line is "bbb". Third line is "ccc". I also have variables with the same names with a value attached. I want to print a line with the line value and value of the variable with the same name. So I want final result as:  aaa |123    and not  aaa |aaa  ... I think DStanley understands what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to implement his dictionary idea ... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Reflection to get the values of your fields based on the names read from the CSV file.

Assuming your strings `aaa`, `bbb` etc are private member variables in the same class as you are reading the CSV file in you should be able to do something like this:

```
while (...)
{
    FieldInfo fieldInfo = this.GetType().GetField(lines[counter], BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if (fieldInfo != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}|{1}|", lines[counter], fieldInfo.GetValue(this).ToString()));
    }
}
```

If the fields are in a different class you'll need to replace `this` with the correct instance to retrieve the values from. If the "fields" are properties you'll need to replace `GetField` with a call to `GetProperty` and finally if the fields are not private or instance variables you'll need to change your `BindingFlags` to match your requirements.

More information on reflection can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173183.aspx).